# Why array self assign value (C program)?

Tags: c, arrays

I declared a two dimensional array as row and col and I left the value empty, but when I  check the value in each array position, some of the indexes contain some weird number.

[image: the picture attached below is the example]

Comment: Why are your `if` and `else` bodies identical? Are you familiar with the **as if** rule?

Comment: Reading uninitialized variable is an undefined behavior.

Comment: Images of code are useless here. [This meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) explains why you should never post code as an image. It's text in your editor, which makes it much easier to copy and paste here than it is to create an image and upload it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking at uninitilized memory. It can have whatever which value to it. You should never trust the value of a variable you haven't initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Access of an uninitialized value is *undefined behavior*. You can solve your problem quite simply by initializing the array to all zero to begin with, e.g.

```
int seatNo[5][5] = {{0}};
```

Now any subsequent access to any of the elements of `seatNo` will succeed because each element has been initialized to zero. As a rule, especially when you are learning C, you will save yourself grief if you simply initialize ALL your variables.

(you will also want to turn warnings on, e.g. `-Wall -Wextra`, at minimum, so your compiler will warn you when a *variable may be uninitialized*)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int seatNo[5][5] = {{0}};

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            printf (" seatNo[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, seatNo[i][j]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example**

```
$ ./bin/initarray
 seatNo[0][0] = 0
 seatNo[0][1] = 0
 seatNo[0][2] = 0
 seatNo[0][3] = 0
 seatNo[0][4] = 0
 seatNo[1][0] = 0
 seatNo[1][1] = 0
<snip>
```